# Next.js: How to change css of root div __next on specific page?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, next.js

I want to change div which the id is **`__next`** on login page.
But when I add style in jsx, it seems change to another div with id **#__next.jsx-2357705899, .main.jsx-2357705899** while dom mounts to page.

How could I change css of **`__next`** div when login page is mount?

```
<style jsx>{`
  #__next,
  .main {
    height: 100%;
  }
`}</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the workarounds you can do is manually adding a class to `#__next` on Login Page and then globally style it

```
import React from 'react';

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById('__next').classList.add('login-page');
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.getElementById('__next').classList.remove('login-page');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Login page
        <style jsx global>{`
          .login-page {
            background-color: red;
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks on the correct road but it's really an ugly way of doing that. See my answer for a proper solution.

Comment: This means you will have to add this code in every component.

Answer (score 43):

Maybe this helps someone.
create a folder "styles" add "globals.css"
add this to that file

```
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer components {
    #__next {
        @apply h-full bg-red-500;
    }
    html,
    body {
        @apply h-full;
    }
}
```

go to your _app.js and import the above stylesheet.

Comment: you may edit and give solution for the specific page

Comment: you sir deserve a medal! thanks for the solution. this is exactly what Ive been searching for!

Comment: Just one upvote for the general public.

Answer (score 34):

Next.JS' Styled JSX allows you to add a `global` keyword to your `<style>` element.
Here's how one would customize the `__next` div.

In your `pages/_document.js` do this:

```
// pages/_document.js
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
          <style jsx global>{`
            /* Other global styles such as 'html, body' etc... */

            #__next {
              height: 100%;
            }
          `}</style>
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest way of dealing with this problem IMO.

Comment: Now `global style` in `_document.js` does not take effect. Style now has to be applied in `_app.js`.

Answer (score 2):

Also the global style idea can be implemented without passing styles into jsx. To me, the solution below looks cleaner:

1. Create `global.css` file (the name doesn't matter)
2. Put the styles inside:

```
/* Other global styles such as 'html, body' etc... */

#__next {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

3. Import the file in your `_app.tsx`:

```
import "../styles/global.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessary anything complex like other answers, just do the following

Create a CSS file as below

`global.css`

```
#__next {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

In `_app.tsx` import the created CSS file.

```
import '../styles/global.css'
```