# How do i remove the div with id="__next" in Next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I am making a website with Next.js. I want to have a header with `position: sticky;` behavior.

However, Next.js automatically generates a div with the attribute `id="__next"` at the root of my website without my permission.

[image]

I need to remove that div so that the `position: sticky;` behavior of my header can work the way it is expected to do. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just add `position: relative;` to `__next` element?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51905803/next-js-how-to-change-css-of-root-div-next-on-specific-page) help?

Comment: Next needs it to mout your app...

Comment: The __next id is required in order to render your app, you could always add some styles to achieve your sticky behavior

Comment: it is the same as asking to remove `root` in react. Nextjs need it to render your web.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot remove it, next.js needs it to render your web app. `position: sticky` always look for it's parent element's height. You can assign `height: 100%; position: relative;` to the `__Next` id. So, it will work as body. And then, your position sticky will work.

Answer (score 4):

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#__next {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

// do whatever you want here and it'll work as expected
```