# How to change div root id in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

I would like to change the root div id and I couldn't find any information if it is possible. I would like it to be my name instead of id="__next". Could someone tell me how I could do this if it's even possible?

Comment: From my understanding you cannot, also look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68656219/how-do-i-remove-the-div-with-id-next-in-next-js , maybe you can find more info

Answer (score 1):

> We're not planning to change #__next anytime soon, as React always needs a root, so you can select this safely. There's no need to add an extra className as that makes the initial HTML document larger.

This is timneutkens's [comment](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4834#issuecomment-430610292), Co-author of Next.js 
So this is not possible

Comment: But I saw that it can. I even found an article about someone rewriting Main's rendering function https://www.codingcrossroads.com/decorating-the-next-js-root-div/ and I found the nodejs file and manually changed the id but I'd rather do it with a function than edit the nodejs file in node_modules to not break anything and for the application to work properly because it needs to have its own id name for the application

Comment: yes, you can add classes to it for styling, but you can't change its `id`. the link you just mentioned is for adding a class and as it is written in the comment it is useless

Comment: This is how I should change the root id in nextjs because I must change it?

Comment: NO! the link shows how to add classes for the root <div> not how tochanging the id name. this is impossible

can you tell me please why do you need that ?

Comment: Since Next.js is based on react and ract allows you to change the name of the root id, it is possible and can be done. I just don't know what function I should rewrite and how it should look like to change my id

Comment: I hope you achieve that